Shared Project with WPF & MAUI specific code in .Net 8.0 class
I have a WPF application just working fine with all the models and view models in a separate project and the WPF views in their own project.
I want to use the same pattern for a MAUI application.
In WPF we use the following code to display a message or error:
MessageBox.Show("ErrStr", "Title", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

In MAUI we use the following code to display a message or error:
await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error Occured", "ErrMsg", "OK");

Now my problem is - how can I structure my application so that I can display a message from the shared project, but using the methods specific to each of the different platforms?

all the Model & ViewModel are in seperate project shared by both WPF & MAUI Projects. How can I achive this

The supposed duplicate cited has nothing to do with the question. See if this Q/A helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882529/how-to-use-messageboxes-in-mvvm. You need to use a service/interface/dependency injection pattern. You'll have one version for WPF and another for MAUI. The shared project will define the interface while the platform specific projects will each implement the interface and then construct and provide an instance of the platform-specific implementation to some class in the shared assembly so it can invoke it as needed via the shared interface.
